# php - ldap group export into csv

Tags: php, ldap

I have a php site that connects to a remote ldap db. The website is an interface to add users, change details of users etc.
I also have an option to get all the uniqeMembers of a group and push them into a csv file the user can download.

Currently i do this one user at a time by looping through each entry and puling out the uid as thats the part im interested in and then getting the first and last name for that user. In small groups its fine but i have some large groups and this process takes far to long and causes the site to timeout.

When looking for a better way to do this ive found using the slapcat command spits out the contents of a group instantly and i can use sed commands to get rid of the bits i dont want. My slapcat command looks something like this:

```
slapcat -a "(entryDN:dnSubtreeMatch:=cn=group_a,dc=abc,dc=xyz)" -l group.csv'
```

My question is really two questions:

1. Is there a better way to achieve this in the php code of my site?
2. If the best way is to use this slapcat command, how can i execute this slapcat command on the remote ldap server and then bring the output file back to my webserver?

Comment: Running commands on remote servers is at best fragile and at worst blocked.  Sounds as though writing something in a language which can extract the data remotely is the best option.

Comment: i was afraid of that. My biggest problem is using the php ldap commands its just to slow and i cant find an option to just spit out all members of a group